# Android AsyncTask without direct access to UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to Android. I have an AsyncTask that is downloading the content of a URL.
I didn't want the AsyncTask to manipulate the UI directly and want it to have it as a reusable peice of code so I have put it in a file of its own and it returns a string.
The problem is that the the return happens before the AsyncTask is finished (even though I am using the .get() of the .excecute()), so I get nothing back.
Here is waht I have at the moment:

```
package com.example.mypackage;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class URLContent {
private String content = "default value";

public String getContent(String URL){
    try {
        new getAsyncContent().execute(URL).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        content = e.getMessage();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        content = e.getMessage();
    }
    return content;
}

private class getAsyncContent extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         content = result;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try{
            return URLResponse(urls[0]);
        } catch (Exception e){
            return e.getMessage();
        }

    }
}

private String IStoString(InputStream stream) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    try {
        return new java.util.Scanner(stream, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return "";
    }
}

private String URLResponse(String URLToget) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(URLToget);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = IStoString(is);
        return contentAsString;
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        } 
    }
}
}
```

What would be the best way to solve that so that my main thread somehow gets back the results?
I have come accross some articles mentioning events and callbacks. Is that the best way..?

Comment: Are you sure it returns before it finishes? May be you your method `URLResponse` returns `null` and you think it is not working. By the way your `AsyncTask` is synchronous by the way you use it.

Comment: As a side note you should follow Java code conventions. Java class has to start with the uppercase letter

Answer (score 2):

Don't do `get()`. Simply have whatever logic deals with result of your URL execution right inside `doInBackground` method. From which you don't have to return anything. In your particular case the problem is that get() is executed right away before the result is delivered

This is asynchronous execution and you can't apply linear logic to it

Comment: But shouldn't it block in `get` until the result is delivered?

Comment: No. It just spawns the thread but get is executed immediately on the UI thread

Comment: I only used the get() in an atempt to get the results.
In my main thread I get the "Default value" but if I output the results in the onPostExecute to a file I get the URL content.

I would ilke to avoid having the logic in the onPostExecute, that was the point, so that I can re-use that code

Comment: According to [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()) it waits until async task finishes.

Comment: AsynkTask is like a Runnable - it will execute `doItInBackground` on some thread it will borrow from the pool. But it will execute it on the separate thread so your comment that AsynkTask is used as synchronous is not true

Comment: Well - "get()" blocks according to JavaDocs, but it does not work the same way across platforms. And it seems not to work in this particular case so I would still handle non-UI stuff in doInBackground perhaps refactoring a method out

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your help. I will try the solution for extending the asyncTask class by Alex, sounds like a clean solution.

I managed to do what I was trying to by using an interface in the class with the AsyncTask and adding an event listener on the main class.
So my class that gets the content now looks like this:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class URLContent {
public void getContent(String URL){
    new getAsyncContent().execute(URL);
}

public interface OnContentDownloadedListener{
    public abstract void onContentDownloaded(String content);
}
private OnContentDownloadedListener contentDownloadedListener = null;
public void setOnContentDownloadedListener(OnContentDownloadedListener content){
    contentDownloadedListener = content;
}

private class getAsyncContent extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        contentDownloadedListener.onContentDownloaded(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try{
            return URLResponse(urls[0]);
        } catch (Exception e){
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}

private String IStoString(InputStream stream) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    try {
        return new java.util.Scanner(stream, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return "";
    }
}

private String URLResponse(String URLToget) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(URLToget);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = IStoString(is);
        return contentAsString;
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        } 
    }
}
}
```

And then in my main class I just have an event listener that handles the update of the UI

```
urlContent.setOnContentDownloadedListener(new URLContent.OnContentDownloadedListener(){
            public void onContentDownloaded(String content){
//update UI or do something with the data
}
```

Comment: Why then you are accepting your own answer instead of Alex's? Give guys his due

Comment: Sorry haven't had time to test Alex's answer yet. I am happy to set it as the answer if you know it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Updating UI with the results of AsyncTask is the main purpose of onPostExecute(). To keep the implementation and the way it's used in UI separate, your Activity can extend your getAsyncContent class and override the onPostExecute() method. This method will be executed on UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

If You do not need UI updates from Your asynchronous task, just create a simple thread to do the things. When complete, just send a broadcast.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do the download here...
        ....
        // 
        sendBroadcast(some_intent);
}).start();
```